# losing variables from javascript array when passing to php

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm trying to implement a page with a choice of user's preferences in an HTML form where if the checkbox *ALL* is selected then all sub-checkbox *base1*, *base2* and *base3* are checked automatically, and if any of sub-checkboxes is un-selected then the checkbox *ALL* must be unchecked. I used a javascript function  which works but when I submit the form only the last variable in the array of checkboxes is sent.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">       
function checkChoice(field, i) {

if (i == 0) { // "All" checkbox selected.
if(field[0].checked==true) {
for (i = 1; i < field.length; i++)
field[i].checked = true;
   }
}
else  {  
if (field[i].checked == false) {
field[0].checked = false;
      }
   }
}
```

```
<form name="form" method = "POST" action="preferences.php">

<input type=checkbox name=classes1 value="allbases" onclick="checkChoice(document.form.classes1, 0)">All bases
</td><td>
<input type=checkbox name=classes1 value="base1" onclick="checkChoice(document.form.classes1, 1)">Base1
<br>
<input type=checkbox name=classes1 value="base2" onclick="checkChoice(document.form.classes1, 2)">Base2
<br>
<input type=checkbox name=classes1 value="base3" onclick="checkChoice(document.form.classes1, 3)">Base3
<input type="submit"  value="Set preferences" >
```

If I call the checkboxes'names in "classes1[]" all the values are submited but the javascript function doesn't work anymore. Is there a way of fixing this? 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an alternative of `checkChoice`: check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592873/check-and-un-check-checkboxes-using-javascript/5593386#5593386) and the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wVCE/) I presented there.

[**edit**] concerning your comment: a bit of extra thinking would have brought you to [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/9d4FP/)

Comment: Thanks, this could work if I had only one set of checkboxes in the form but I have six different sets like the one I posted so I cannot use getElementsbyTagName(input).

Comment: @Kooilnc Thank your for your help (I'm not at all familiar with javascript), in the end the combination works for me `function checkChoice(field, k) {
if (field[k].checked == false) {
field[0].checked = false;
      }
}

function flipCbs(obj) {
 var cbs = document.getElementById('theForm').getElementsByTagName('input'),
     l = cbs.length,
     rangeid = obj.id.substr(0,2);

 while (l--){
  if (cbs[l].type.match(/checkbox/i)
       && cbs[l] !== obj
       && cbs[l].id.substr(0,2) === rangeid) {    
   cbs[l].checked = obj.checked; 
  }
 }
}`

Comment: @Kooilnc actually, the combination  doesn't work as the POST array is always re-written but I'll keep trying.

Comment: @Kooilnc I used your function to create another I needed like this and it finally works!  `function flip(obj) {
 var commons = document.getElementById('theForm').getElementsByTagName('input'),
     k = commons.length,
     rangeid = obj.id.substr(0,2);

 while (k--){
  if (obj.checked==false&&commons[k].type.match(/checkbox/i)&&commons[k].id.substr(0,2) === rangeid&&commons[0].checked == true) {    
   commons[0].checked = obj.checked; 
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Hi Tomasole, glad I could contribute. Javascript is a nice & powerfull language once you get the hang of it.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

All of the values actually ARE submitted but PHP will overwrite $_POST['classes1'] each time until you are just left with the last value. If however you add '[]' to your input names then they are added to an array.

Since the latter causes a problem with javascript, can you not just either
a) iterate all of the form elements from the form.elements array, 
or b) give each input a unique id and use document.getElementById() to find it?